# Is it possible to use Detox in a separate Repo from my React Native Application?

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, playwright, detox

I have a repository titled QA-Services for my playwright tests for my web apps. Now I am getting Detox setup for my mobile applications.

Yes, all 4 directories in my repo are for the same parent product but just different versions. My QA-Services repo looks like this:

```
qa-services
 - h-m-mobile
  - detox stuff
 - h-m-web
  - playwright stuff
 - v-m-mobile
  - detox stuff
 - v-m-web
  - playwright stuff
```

My issue currently is I am trying to run detox init to initialize the h-m-mobile directory and nothing is happening. I am getting no errors, warnings, failures, etc in the console. The files are also not being created. I have followed all the setup steps in detox's documentation but still no luck.

This got me wondering if detox is able to run outside the application the same way playwright can run away since all it needs is the website link.

Any help appreciated!